# WIFI - Single radio acting as AP and AP Client simultaneously

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Is it possible for a single (802.11 b,g,n,ac) WIFI radio to act as both an Access Point and Access Point client simultaneously - if so how, and  are there examples of software that allow this (I'm particularly interested in Linux, but any OS that does it would evidence it can be done, and thus valuable to me).  If not, why not?

For the sake of clarity, I'm not talking about a radio acting as either one or the other, and switching roles at different times, nor am I talking about 2 radios on different frequencies doing different jobs.   I'm also not interested in ad-hoc mode unless this can be leveraged to appear as an AP and AP client to other AP's and AP clients respectively.

Comment: I think using 802.11 b/g/n/ac is dual frequency, so the software will see 2 radio interface, but in any case simultaneous wifi client+access point is support in LEDE (see https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/relay_configuration). I run this firmware on all my routers for years (was running openwrt before the fork).

Comment: Thank you for this - Looking at https://www.circuidipity.com/openwrt-bridged-repeater/ I can see that there are 2 wifi interfaces with the same radio in bot AP and station mode, so this must be possible.  You should make it an answer.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/649220/a-wifi-ap-with-a-single-nic, specifically the "possible combinations" report in `iw phy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modes of operation**

The access point, providing WiFi is usually called **AP**, while the client is called **STA**.

It's possible to configure your device as a [repeater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater) or as something I will call a wireless-wireless router, since I can't find a consensual name.

- The **repeater** will **bridge** (transmit all Ethernet packets between STA and AP sides), using the existing network infrastructure for [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), routing, ...
- The **wireless-wireless router**  will **route** selected packets between the STA and the AP side, providing DHCP and [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

The **wireless-wireless router** will need more configuration, but will only transmit packet as needed.

**Hardware compatibility**

Some wireless adapter are not able to use STA and AP mode at the same time (some adapters even can't serve as AP).

If you've got an adapter at hand, `iw list` can be used to establish if it is able to do act as an client and access point at the same time. As said in this [question](https://superuser.com/q/649220/201468), you must look for the `valid interface combinations` part of the `iw list` command.

**About the single 802.11 a/b/g/ac radio**

Since 802.11 b/g/n uses 2.4 GHz and 802.11 a/ac uses 5 GHz, the adapter will need at least 2 phy, and will probably need to be configured as 2 separate access point, from the Linux point of view.

**About the software**

They are plenty of dedicated Linux distribution targeting small computers and WiFi routers, here are some examples:

- [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/), a fork of [openwrt](https://www.openwrt.org)
- [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)
- [dd-wrt](https://dd-wrt.com/)

All the previously listed distributions have their own flag on superuser.

**About the WRT name**

Interestingly, a lot of router-targeted Linux distributions contain the WRT *word*, since they started as an alternative firmware for the venerable [LinkSys WRT54G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series).

Comment: "wireless-wireless router" mode, as you name it, is called AP+STA in openwrt (https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/ap_sta)

Comment: @pim The term `router` is largely accepted as a layer3 device where each port exists in a different subnet, and it routes between those subsets.  A home gateway is a router, a border gateway within the ISPs network is a router - but what you described is in a lower layer than that - IMO we should avoid that term here.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done (depending on Wi-Fi device capabilities). I believe "Wi-Fi Direct" turns it into an official feature (e.g. a TV simultaneously acting as a station on the home network, and as access point for direct video transfer), but it's also possible to have just a regular AP.

#### Clueless attempt at explanation

As far as I know, the physical radio behaves the same whether it's an AP or a station – at least in "simpler" modes like 802.11b/g/n (perhaps it's more complex in 802.11ac). That is, it does not need to *switch* between incompatible "AP" and "STA" behaviors.

Instead it just sends different kinds of frames. If the firmware allows it, then it can freely send "AP-like" and "STA-like" frames at the same time. This is especially true for "SoftMAC" devices, which (unlike "FullMAC" ones) defer most of the control to the OS and drivers.

#### Configuring it in practice

I don't really know how it works; I'm just writing the post because I have tested it on my own hardware.

- For example, here's what `iw phy` says about an Atheros ath9k series adapter. (It's several years old, 2.4 GHz only, but is a "SoftMAC" device – meaning that the driver handles everything and is free to do *a lot* of weird stuff.)

  ```
  valid interface combinations:
           * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
             total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
           * #{ WDS } <= 2048,
             total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
  ```

  Each `*` line is a single combination list. So I can associate to 2000 networks as a station *and* host 8 networks as an AP; of course they must all remain on a single channel (`#channels <= 1`).<sup>[1]</sup>
- Similarly, here's an Intel "Wireless 3160" adapter. Since it supports 802.11ac, it does a lot more work in the firmware (i.e. is a "FullMAC" device) and therefore is constrained by what the firmware can do.<sup>[2]</sup>

  ```
  valid interface combinations:
           * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
             total <= 3, #channels <= 2
  ```

  So, since the modes are now firmware-based rather than driver-based, you can only have one of each – but you can still be a station *and* an AP.

  It also says `#channels <= 2` – not just because it's dual-band, but because it can even work on two *same band* channels. I believe they've made it possible because Wi-Fi Direct requires it – in my tests on 2.4 GHz band, if I use different channels, my phone shows a "[P2P]" marker next to the laptop's SSID. If I use the same channel, the phone just shows a regular AP.

As for how to configure it:

1. First, use `iw` to add a new virtual device on top of the same "phy" (physical adapter). By default your adapter is `phy0`, and has one network interface `wlan0`. So add a second one:

   ```
   iw phy phy0 interface add wlan1 type __ap                 # [sic]
   ```

   If you want to host a network, *normally* you'd use `type managed` and expect `hostapd` to switch the interface to AP mode, but for some reason that doesn't happen when multiple interfaces exist. So instead you may have to pre-create it in AP mode directly.
2. Second, just configure `hostapd` to use that interface as you normally would.

---

<sup>1</sup> (The "BI must match" restriction [is explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/649220/a-wifi-ap-with-a-single-nic).)
<sup>2</sup> (Still better than some Realtek or Broadcom devices, which don't even support AP mode at all!)

Answer (score 1):

I always find the [Arch Linux Wiki a good source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point). There‘s also a section „[Wireless client and software AP with a single Wi-Fi device](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device)“.