# What Wifi USB adaptors could work in __ap and station mode at once

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I followed [these instructions](https://superuser.com/q/615664) and still can't get AP working on the same interface. I have these devices:

Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R is giving me an error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: No buffer space available
```

Linksys WUSB600N v2 Dual-Band Wireless-N Network Adapter [Ralink RT3572] (USB wifi adaptor):

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

these errors occur when I start second virtual interface on the same wifi device. What wifi adaptors support two virtual interfaces? What should I look for in hardware specifications? Maybe there are already known USB wifi adaptors that could work as AP and uplink at once?

Comment: AFAIU, a WiFi adapter can do one or the other, not both at the same time. Perhaps get a cheap USB WiFi adapter as complement?

Comment: In my situation I can have just one wifi device.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can verify if (and under what conditions) your adapter supports simultaneous STA and AP operation by examining the output of

```
iw phy<n> info
```

where `n` is the number of your adapter, e.g. `phy0`.

In the output, there is a section called `valid interface combinations`; here is an example of an adapter that supports simultaneous STA and AP operation, but only on the same channel and using an equal broadcast interval:

```
[...]
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1,
       total <= 2, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
     * #{ managed } <= 2,
       total <= 2, #channels <= 1
[....]
```